# Why the window interval timer id doesn't start from 0?

Tags: javascript

I want to know why the window interval timer starts from 132 or another number.

Chrome/75.0.3770.142 DevTool Console

```js
const id = setInterval(()=>{
  console.log('hey bro');
},1000);
console.log(id);
```

1. Why it doesn't start from 0?
2. 0~131 what means in browser?

Comment: setInterval returns an indentifier, not a interval

Comment: Why do you care what number it returns?

Comment: @guijob I know setInterval returns an indentifier.Why it doesn't start from 0?

Comment: @JLRishe Curious.

Answer (score 0):

[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) returns an identifier for you be able to stop it later using [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval). Example:

```js
const id = setInterval(()=>{
    console.log('hey bro');
},1000);

setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(id);
}, 5001);
```